# Set up MIME::Lite on Windows 7 without Outlook

Tags: perl, email, mime, mail-server

I run ActiveState's ActivePerl on my Windows 7 box. I just installed the MIME::Lite module using the PPM (Perl Package Manager). The installation went fine.

However, as I try to run a very simple script

```
use strict;
use MIME::Lite;

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
        From     => 'myname@host.com',
        To       => 'myname@host.com',
        Subject  => "Mail Test",
        Data     => "Test Test!!",
    );
$msg->send;
```

I got this error:

```
SMTP Failed to connect to mail server: at C:\...\mail_test.pl line 10
```

Does that mean I need to install a 3rd party mail server on my windows? Or can I configure the script and/or windows to make it work without new installation? In particular, I do *not* run outlook on that machine. Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give it a host to send the mail through, otherwise its going to try and use the SMTP server on your computer which A) you don't have and B) if its a home computer [many would reject it as spam anyway](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Dialup_Users_List).

The [MIME::Lite documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME::Lite) shows how to [tell it what SMTP host to use](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MIME::Lite#Change_how_messages_are_sent).  Set it up with the same host, username and password as you would your normal mail client.

Unfortunately, MIME::Lite doesn't support encryption so your mail will be going out insecure and in the clear.  Some mail servers won't even talk unencrypted any more.  [Email::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Sender::Manual::QuickStart) I believe is what the email folks recommend you use these days.